# How do I set up bitcoind to track all address balances?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

Bitcoind only stores information about addresses that you've added.

How do I make it store balance and transaction information for *all* addresses so that given any address I've never seen before, I can quickly query the information? I need responses in less than 1 second.

I dont want to use any centralized apis like blockcypher or blockchain.com.

Comment: Try one of the open source block explorers which can be used with bitcoind: 1. [Mempool](https://github.com/mempool/mempool) 2. [Esplora](https://github.com/Blockstream/esplora) 3. [NBXplorer](https://github.com/dgarage/NBXplorer)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported feature. Only the wallet tracks total balances (per wallet even, not per address), and only does so for your own keys/addresses (including imported "watch only" keys/addresses).

Other software exists that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Better check https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore or other open-source blockchain's indexer. But no bitcoind is not made to support this "top level" functionality